# how to pick single data row from DB using link (A tag)

Tags: laravel

here is my Data Requesting link

```
<input type="Hidden" name="addid" value="{{$add->id}}">
<a href="{{route('PickAdd',[app()->getLocale(),'id'=>$add->id]) }}"class="btn btn-success ">{{ __('View More') }}</a>
```

then this is connect with Route like this

```
Route::get('/PickAdd/{id}', 'MAddController@view')->name('PickAdd');
```

controller is like this

```
public function view($id)
    { //dd($id);
      $Padd = Madd::find('$id');
      return view('adds.add',compact('Padd','id'));
     }
```

this controlling function not working.
but I change like this

```
$Padd = Madd::find('22');
```

then it works,
**that mean $id =22**

**if I run DD, result is null**
according to my knowledge my code cant catch passing data from front end, can you help me to solve this

Comment: It is because you are passing string `$id` and not the value of `$id`, remove single quotes `'`, change it to `$Padd = Madd::find($id);`

Comment: I did that , this error is showing --- Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/resources/views/adds/add.blade.php)---

Comment: The `find()` method works when the record  exists. Instead of using find, try  first

Comment: @sameera: It is because `{{$add->id}}` you are passing `Padd` and not `add`, Replace `Padd` to `add` and `$Padd` to `$add`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$id` as a `string` from your controller

**Change**

```
$Padd = Madd::find('$id');
```

**to**

```
$Padd = Madd::find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `find()` method, in case the record does not exist. Use  `first()`

```
$Padd = Madd::where('id',$id)->first();
```

That works when the record exists or not.

Also, look in the Madd model is you defined another primary key other than id, like

```
protected  $primaryKey = 'some-other-key';
```

because that would force Eloquent to look for that instead of the `id`

Comment: Try  this in your controller :

`public function view($id)
    { //dd($id);
      $Padd = Madd::find('$id');
      return view('adds.add', ['Padd',$Padd] );
     }`

Comment: it also null, but this code is working [$Pdds = Madd::where('id',request('id'))->paginate(32);
            return view('adds.add',['Pdds'=> $Pdds ]); ]    this is for multiple rows, if I use I have to use [   @foreach($Padds ?? '' as $Padd)]

Comment: It is a bit concerning though that your controller parses as string as an integer. I would use something  different

`public function view( Request $request )
    { //dd($id);
      $Padd = Madd::find( (int)$request->id );
      return view('adds.add', ['Padd',$Padd] );
     }`